# How copy text into Terminal command line zsh?

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina, copy-paste, zsh

Somehow something seems to have been changed with my Zsh configuration or Terminal settings under macOS Catalina (10.15.7). If I copy some text, say from a TextEdit window, the usual paste command and shortcut-key (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>) no longer paste that text onto the command line in Terminal.

How to fix this so it works as expected?

Comment: "The usual command/shortcut key" is vague.  What command were you using previously?

Comment: @Allan: Cmd-c for copy, Cmd-v for paste (without the hyphens, of course)

Comment: If you go into Terminal, then from the Menu Bar, select Edit, then Paste does it work?  What key combination does it show?

Comment: The problem arose from an error in my `.profile`, which is loaded by `.zshrc`. With `.profile` fixed, copy/paste into Terminal works normally.

Comment: It's helpful if you clarify what you're asking and then add an answer (don't "update" the question) with what you did to solve it.  This way it will help others who run into this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I discovered that the problem arose from an error in my .profile, which is loaded by .zshrc. With .profile fixed, copy/paste into Terminal works normally, whether with usual Cmd-C/Cmd-V keyboard cominations or Edit menu selections.

Comment: What exactly was the problem and how did you fix it?

Comment: @nohillside: Sorry, I don't recall exactly what the type was there now. May have been a simple matter of unmatched quotes, even.